# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on self in block

Tags: ios, objective-c

I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS/KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS on line "self handleError:error ..etc"

I thought that the block will retain self? "self" is a viewController which is probably popped off the stack, but shouldn't it be retained?

```
[[PWGamesResource sharedInstance] createRandomGameRequest:requestDict
        withFailure:^(NSError *error) {
            [self handleError:error withTryAgain:^{
                [self sendNewRandomGameRequest:difficulty];
            }];
        }];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `self` getting deallocated is indeed your real problem, the complete solution is to strongly reference a weak reference of self inside the block so you can get rid of the risk of having it deallocated while executing inside the block:

Get a strong reference to your weak pointer inside the block.

```
__weak MyObject *weakSelf = self; // a weak reference of self so you can avoid any retain cycles
myBlock = ^{
  MyObject *innerSelf = weakSelf; // a block-local strong reference so that you can avoid to have weakSelf deallocated while executing
  NSLog(@"MyObject: %@", innerSelf); 
};
```

Avoid using the variables directly, because it will cause retain cycles. 
If you use an instance variable directly within a block, the block will capture self so you'll have to reference the instance variables using their accessors.

```
__weak MyObject *weakSelf = self;
myBlock = ^{
    MyObject *innerSelf = weakSelf; // a block-local strong reference
    NSLog(@"MyObject: %@", innerSelf);
    NSLog(@"MyObject ID: %d", innerSelf.objectID);// accessing the property through the block's strong reference to self
};
```

If you use the instance variables directly like this:

```
NSLog(@"MyObject ID: %d", _objectID);
```

The compiler interprets `_objectID` as `self->_objectID`, where self is captured by your block.

Answer (score -2):

You should avoid using self in blocks where possible.

Try this:

```
__weak __typeof(self)weakSelf = self;

[[PWGamesResource sharedInstance] createRandomGameRequest:requestDict
        withFailure:^(NSError *error) {
            [weakSelf handleError:error withTryAgain:^{
                [weakSelf sendNewRandomGameRequest:difficulty];
            }];
        }];
```

Comment: Your solution is incomplete. You only get a weak pointer to self so that you can break a retain cycle without having it strongly referenced inside the block which could cause your reference to get deallocated while it executes inside the block.